# How to solve Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError because of poi.ss.util.CellReference.<init>?

Tags: java, apache-poi, exe4j

I make a script to read excel file, And it's no problem to run on IDEA IDK or  cmd by `java -jar script.jar` .

[image]

However, when I use exe4j to transfer EXE file. It reports error like:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference.<init>(CellReference.java:109)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.<init>(XSSFCell.java:117)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow.<init>(XSSFRow.java:74)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.initRows(XSSFSheet.java:270)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.read(XSSFSheet.java:233)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.onDocumentRead(XSSFSheet.java:220)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.parseSheet(XSSFWorkbook.java:452)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onDocumentRead(XSSFWorkbook.java:417)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:184)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:286)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:307)
    at proect.Util.Excel_Util.readDataSet(Excel_Util.java:90)
    at proect.Util.Excel_Util.dealDataset(Excel_Util.java:54)
    at proect.Main.<init>(Main.java:58)
    at proect.Main$10.run(Main.java:578)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: Big5
    at java.base/java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Charset.java:527)
    at org.apache.poi.util.StringUtil.<clinit>(StringUtil.java:39)
    ... 28 more
```

The D1.excel is the file to read. The excel code like:

```
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void readDataSet(String filePath){
        InputStream in;
        DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
        try{
            Excel_Util eu = new Excel_Util();
            ClassLoader cl = eu.getClass().getClassLoader();
             in = cl.getResourceAsStream("D1.xlsx");

            //input = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(in);
            XSSFSheet sheet = book.getSheetAt(0);
            XSSFRow row;
            for(int i=sheet.getFirstRowNum()+1;i<sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();++i){
                row = sheet.getRow(i);
                Scheme_No_Column.add(row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
                Pv_Capacity_Column.add(row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
                Device_No_Column.add(row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue());
                Power_Column.add(formatter.formatCellValue(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(3)));
            }

            }catch(FileNotFoundException IOE){
                System.out.println("文件不在正确的位置（the file is not found in the location）");

            }catch(IOException IOE){
                System.out.println("Excel的文件内容不正确（the content of the excel is not correct）");
            }

        }
```

The awt code like:

```
package proect;

/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/GUIForms/JFrame.java to edit this template
 */

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Lenovo
 */

import proect.Util.Excel_Util;
import proect.Util.Regular_Match_Engine;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

import proect.PV.Devices;
import proect.PV.PV_Modules;



public class Main extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Home
     */
    //private static boolean loop = true;
    private static int case_=2;
    
    JFrame frame_1 = new JFrame();
    
     JProgressBar bar = new JProgressBar();
    
    Excel_Util excel = new Excel_Util();
    
    PV_Modules pv = new PV_Modules();
    
    ArrayList<Devices> List = new ArrayList();
        
    Regular_Match_Engine RME = new Regular_Match_Engine();

    
    
    
    
    public Main() {
        
        //handle data
        
        List = excel.dealDataset("./src/main/java/proect/dataset/D1.xlsx");
        
        List = pv.mergeDevices(List);
        
        //TextAreaOutputStream st = new TextAreaOutputStream(jTextArea1,"output");
         
        //
        
        //Begin_frame_1();
        //frame_1.dispose();
        ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        String path = this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
        
        this.setTitle("光伏型号筛选脚本");
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(path+"/petro.png");
        this.setIconImage(image.getImage());
        initComponents();
       
       
        
    }
    
    
  

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        bg = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        sidepane = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        btn_search = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        btn_exit = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
        btn_pv1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel11 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        bg.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

        sidepane.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(54, 33, 89));
        sidepane.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        btn_search.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(64, 43, 100));
        btn_search.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                btn_searchMousePressed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Microsoft YaHei UI Light", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));
        jLabel2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel2.setText("1. 简单全局搜索");
        jLabel2.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jLabel2MouseClicked(evt);
            }
            public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jLabel2MousePressed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout btn_searchLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(btn_search);
        btn_search.setLayout(btn_searchLayout);
        btn_searchLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            btn_searchLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(btn_searchLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(71, 71, 71)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addContainerGap(83, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        btn_searchLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            btn_searchLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(btn_searchLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(43, 43, 43)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        sidepane.add(btn_search, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 180, 240, 60));

        jPanel3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(85, 65, 118));
        jPanel3.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jPanel3MousePressed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Microsoft YaHei UI Light", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));
        jLabel4.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel4.setText("欢迎来到筛选脚本");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
        jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
        jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(75, 75, 75)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addContainerGap(66, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(41, 41, 41)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        sidepane.add(jPanel3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 120, 240, 60));

        btn_exit.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(64, 43, 100));
        btn_exit.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                btn_exitMousePressed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Microsoft YaHei UI Light", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel6.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));
        jLabel6.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel6.setText("3. 离开脚本");
        jLabel6.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jLabel6MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout btn_exitLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(btn_exit);
        btn_exit.setLayout(btn_exitLayout);
        btn_exitLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            btn_exitLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(btn_exitLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(71, 71, 71)
                .addComponent(jLabel6)
                .addContainerGap(106, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        btn_exitLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            btn_exitLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(btn_exitLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(42, 42, 42)
                .addComponent(jLabel6)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        sidepane.add(btn_exit, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 310, 240, 60));

        jLabel9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Mistral", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel9.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));
        jLabel9.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel9.setText("KeepToo");
        sidepane.add(jLabel9, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(80, 20, -1, -1));
        sidepane.add(jSeparator1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, 40, 190, 10));

        btn_pv1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(64, 43, 100));
        btn_pv1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                btn_pv1MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel11.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Microsoft YaHei UI Light", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel11.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));
        jLabel11.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel11.setText("2. 光伏设备容量查询");
        jLabel11.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jLabel11MouseClicked(evt);
            }
            public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jLabel11MousePressed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout btn_pv1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(btn_pv1);
        btn_pv1.setLayout(btn_pv1Layout);
        btn_pv1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            btn_pv1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(btn_pv1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(69, 69, 69)
                .addComponent(jLabel11)
                .addContainerGap(65, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        btn_pv1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            btn_pv1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(btn_pv1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(47, 47, 47)
                .addComponent(jLabel11)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        sidepane.add(btn_pv1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 240, -1, 70));

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(110, 89, 222));

        jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Microsoft YaHei UI Light", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel7.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));
        jLabel7.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel7.setText("管理系统");

        jTextField1.setText("输入光伏容量((kWp))...");
        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel10.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Microsoft YaHei UI Light", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel10.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel10.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel10.setText("请输入关键词：__________________________________________");

        jButton2.setText("确认");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(65, 65, 65)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 403, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel7)
                                .addGap(111, 111, 111)))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 78, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addComponent(jLabel10))
                .addContainerGap(87, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel7)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 27, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel10)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)))
        );

        jLabel8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Microsoft YaHei UI Light", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel8.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 255));
        jLabel8.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel8.setText("搜索结果如下：");

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout bgLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(bg);
        bg.setLayout(bgLayout);
        bgLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            bgLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(bgLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(sidepane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 234, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(bgLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(bgLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(12, 12, 12)
                        .addComponent(jLabel8))
                    .addGroup(bgLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(bgLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 526, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        bgLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            bgLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(bgLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(sidepane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(bgLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(47, 47, 47)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 35, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel8)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 259, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(31, 31, 31))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(bg, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(bg, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    private void jLabel11MousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jLabel11MousePressed
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        resetColor(btn_search);
        resetColor(btn_exit);
        setColor(btn_pv1);
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jLabel11MousePressed

    private void jPanel3MousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jPanel3MousePressed
        // TODO add your handling code here:
       
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jPanel3MousePressed

    private void btn_searchMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_btn_searchMousePressed
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        setColor(btn_search);
        resetColor(btn_exit);
        resetColor(btn_pv1);
    }//GEN-LAST:event_btn_searchMousePressed

    private void btn_exitMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_btn_exitMousePressed
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        resetColor(btn_search);
        setColor(btn_exit);
        resetColor(btn_pv1);
    }//GEN-LAST:event_btn_exitMousePressed

    private void jLabel2MousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jLabel2MousePressed
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jLabel2MousePressed

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jTextField1ActionPerformed
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jTextField1ActionPerformed

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton2ActionPerformed
        if(case_==1){
            String searchContent = jTextField1.getText();
            RME.Text_matching(List, searchContent);
            jTextArea1.setText(""+RME.getString());
            RME.clear();
        }else if(case_==2){
             String searchContent = jTextField1.getText();
             RME.Pv_Capacity_matching(List, searchContent);
             jTextArea1.setText(""+RME.getString());
             RME.clear();
        }
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jButton2ActionPerformed

    //点击选项1
    private void jLabel2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jLabel2MouseClicked
        case_=1;
        jTextField1.setText("输入关键词"); 


        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jLabel2MouseClicked

    private void btn_pv1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_btn_pv1MouseClicked
        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }//GEN-LAST:event_btn_pv1MouseClicked

    private void jLabel11MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jLabel11MouseClicked
        case_=2;
         jTextField1.setText("输入光伏容量(kWp)");
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jLabel11MouseClicked

    private void jLabel6MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jLabel6MouseClicked
        System.exit(0); // TODO add your handling code here:
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jLabel6MouseClicked

    
    void setColor(JPanel panel){
        panel.setBackground(new Color(85,65,118));
    }
    
    void resetColor(JPanel panel){
        panel.setBackground(new Color(63,43,100));
    }
    
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Main().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private javax.swing.JPanel bg;
    private javax.swing.JPanel btn_exit;
    private javax.swing.JPanel btn_pv1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel btn_search;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel11;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel sidepane;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

I don't understand why it reports error when transfering from ***.java*** to ***.exe***. Could someone help me, thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/beryx/badass-runtime-plugin/issues/44 and https://github.com/traccar/traccar/issues/4126

Comment: Key line is `Caused by: java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: Big5` - what happens if you include all the Java Character Sets in your JVM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved problem and thanks for XtremeBaumer and Gagravarr.

**Reasons：**
Because the JVM cannot support the Character. I create such a converter，which could call the available character set when using the exclusive characters.

**Method：**
Firstly, I create a file named ***java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider*** in the folder of META-INF/services.
Then, I create **ChineseCharsetProvider.java** in project folder.

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class ChineseCharsetProvider extends CharsetProvider {
    private static final String GB2312 = "GB2312";
    private static final String BIG5 = "Big5";
    private static final String GBK = "GBK";

    @Override
    public Iterator<Charset> charsets() {
        return Collections.emptyIterator();
    }

    @Override
    public Charset charsetForName(String charsetName) {
        if (GB2312.equalsIgnoreCase(charsetName) || BIG5.equalsIgnoreCase(charsetName))
            return Charset.forName(GBK);
        return Charset.defaultCharset();
    }
}
```